# Error using preg_replace function

Tags: php, html

I want to replace only

```
<span class="google-src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left">any character</span>
```

line by line with space in this source http://persianfox.ir/html.html and my php code is

```
$content = file_get_contents('path/to/html.html');
$content = str_replace('>', ">\n", $content);

echo preg_replace('/<span class="google-src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left">.*.<\/span>/', ' ', $content);
```

but this code will replace all the content that beign with `<span class="google-src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left">` and last `</span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is *greedy* by default, you need to change it to *lazy*, like so:

```
preg_replace('/<span class="google-src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left">.*?<\/span>/', ' ', $content);
//                                                               Note the question mark ^
```

This will match *up to the first `</span>`, note that if you have a nested span inside, it will not fetch all the way to the end.

That's why **[You shouldn't parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)** and should instead use a **[proper HTML DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)**

Answer (score 1):

This one works if you have no HTML in your "any character".

```
/<span class="google-src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left">([^<]{1,})<\/span>/
```